# JavaFx application in a mac os whitout monitor attached

Tags: java, macos

I've developed a javafx application that downloads files from amazon s3. Everything works like expected in my machine but when i copy it on the destination mac mini i get a strange error. 
Gui is not drawn until window is resized ( i attach a screenshot ). I've tried to attach a monitor to that mini and my application works as expected so the issue here is that there's no monitor.
Has anyone got this issue and solved ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested.. use something like [this dummy dongle](https://macminicolo.net/blog/files/build-a-dummy-dongle-for-a-headless-mac-mini.html) to make the operating system guess there's a monitor attached, enabling video card